# How can I get Left, Top, Height and Witdth properties in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, properties, location, size

How can I have in Visual Studio 2010, the properties "Location" and "Size" replaced by "Left", "Top", "Height" and "Width" in the properties window during design time ?

I find annoying when graphically designing a component to have to expand each time the Location or Size group to fill the values that I need. When I have something like "Size: 305;105" I always forgot which number is the height and which is the width. Same goes for the location where "Top" and "Left" are way more meaningful for me.

[image: screenshot]

I think they call this Nested properties.

Thanks for the help,

Joël

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be categoric on this, but looking at the source code of the class Control (from which the Form class is derived) I can see this for the property Left

```
[EditorBrowsable(0), SRCategory("CatLayout"), Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(0), SRDescription("ControlLeftDescr")]
public int Left { [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")] get; set; }
```

The attribute [EditorBrowsable(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) means

> EditorBrowsableAttribute is a hint to a designer indicating whether a
>   property or method is to be displayed. You can use this type in a
>   visual designer or text editor to determine what is visible to the
>   user. For example, the IntelliSense engine in Visual Studio uses this
>   attribute to determine whether to show a property or method.
>   In Visual C#, you can control when advanced properties appear in
>   IntelliSense and the Properties Window with the Hide Advanced Members
>   setting under Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#. The corresponding
>   EditorBrowsableState is Advanced.

Sadly, also after removing that flag in Visual Studio 2013 I am not able to show these properties in the Properties Window as individual entries, however they are visible as the Intellisense pops up. So I could only conclude that it is not possible to change the behavior of the standard Properties Window.

Hint to remember the relative positions of the two numbers:

- First=Horizontal Axis
- Second=Vertical Axis